kendo ui js not allow extra white space in string
I have data stored database, as "Hello  World" (have extra space between two word), but as the data load to Kendo UI JS, it became "Hello World" (remove extra white space).

Multiple spaces in a text string when rendered as html, for example within a span or div, display in the browser as a single space. This is just how browsers work and is not a kendo ui issue. If you want every space to actually be rendered as such, you will need to replace each space in the string with the non-breaking space character.
<span>Hello&nbsp;&nbsp;World</span>

That element will render with two spaces. An alternative is to use the 'pre' element which will render the text exactly without having to replace the spaces with the non-breaking space character.
<pre>Hello  World</pre>

This is the best I can infer from the limited detail in your question.
